# grep: can't open nohup.out

Tags: unix, grep, aix, nohup

I am doing recursive grep (grep -r) but it is failing saying

```
grep: can't open nohup.out
```

How to make it going and grep in all directories. I have some idea about nohup but I am not interested in it. I just want my grep to complete.

Comment: Could you please show the command (with parameters) you are running?

Comment: Do you have any updates? Would be interested in why this happens…

Answer (score 2):

If `grep` complains about not being able to open a file, it should still continue searching.

You can suppress error output by

- using the `-s` option for `grep`, or
- adding `2> /dev/null` to your command

Comment: No its not just complaining..it's failing on that. I think these methods will only suppress error msg, not keeps grep going.

Comment: Please show the actual command you're using and a long-format `ls` of the files you're grepping over. Does a file called `nohup.out` exist, and if so, can you delete it?

Comment: @Ahmad The most likely scenario, if I was to guess, is that someone ran a "sudo nohup ..." command at one point and left a root-owned nohup.out file that your user is unable to open.